# Parameter error when running selenium webdriver test case in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parameter-passing, testng

I'm trying to run this method in Selenium webdriver but I continue to get this error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method PopulateBorrower requires 2 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:198)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:370)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:447)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1384)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

--------->what am I doing wrong? The code is below. I have its's setup in a SetUpBase separate class.

```
@Test
public static void PopulateBorrower(String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1,String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName)
{       
    String fName= PrimaryBorrowerInputDictionary.get(BorrowerFirstNameElement);
    String lName=PrimaryBorrowerInputDictionary.get(BorrowerLastNameElement);
    String suffix=PrimaryBorrowerInputDictionary.get(BorrowerSuffixElement);
    String social=PrimaryBorrowerInputDictionary.get(BorrowerSocialSecurityNumberElement);
    String homePhone=PrimaryBorrowerInputDictionary.get(BorrowerHomePhoneNumberElement);
    String schoolYears=PrimaryBorrowerInputDictionary.get(BorrowerYearsInSchoolElement);

    driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1 + BorrowerFirstNameElement)).sendKeys(fName);
    driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1 + BorrowerLastNameElement)).sendKeys(lName);
    driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1 + BorrowerSuffixElement)).sendKeys(suffix);
    driver.findElement(By.name(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerHomePhoneNumberElement)).sendKeys(social);

    driver.findElement(By.name(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerHomePhoneNumberElement)).sendKeys(homePhone);
    driver.findElement(By.name(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerYearsInSchoolElement)).sendKeys(schoolYears);
    driver.findElement(By.name(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName +BorrowerMarriageStatusElement )).click();


    assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerFirstNameElement))
                .getText(), fName);

    assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerLastNameElement))
            .getText(), lName);

    assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerSuffixElement))
            .getText(), suffix);

    assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerHomePhoneNumberElement))
            .getText(), homePhone);

    assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerYearsInSchoolElement))
            .getText(), schoolYears);

    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName + BorrowerMarriageStatusElement))
            .isSelected());
 }
```

Comment: Did you resolve it ?

Comment: @Emna this is `TestNGException` for un-supplied parameters in `@Test` method. I have added both approaches provided by `TestNG` to do the same. You can try that out. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The `TestNGException` is coming because your `@Test` method requires 2 parameters (i.e. `PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1` and `PrimaryBorrowerBaseName`) but you are not passing them.

To solve this you need to supply these parameters when `TestNG` invokes your `@Test` method (i.e. `PopulateBorrower`). `TestNG` provides 2 ways to do the same.

### Supplying [parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) in `TestNG`

1. [Parameters from testng.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml)
2. [Parameters with DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

> You can try any one of below approach to solve your issue.

### Solution 1: Parameters from testng.xml

**The `testng.xml` file**:

```
<suite name="My Suite">
    <parameter name="primary-borrower-base-name1" value="value1" />
    <parameter name="primary-borrower-base-name"  value="value"/>
    <test name="My Test">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="yourpackage.PopulateBorrowerTestClass2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Your test class**:

```
package yourpackage;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PopulateBorrowerTestClass2 {

    @Parameters({ "primary-borrower-base-name1", "primary-borrower-base-name" })
    @Test
    public static void PopulateBorrower(String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1, String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName)
    {       
        System.out.println(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1 + " " + PrimaryBorrowerBaseName);
       //your all code goes here
     }
}
```

### Solution 2: Parameters with DataProviders

**The `testng.xml` file**:

```
<suite name="My Suite">
    <test name="My Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="yourpackage.PopulateBorrowerTestClass1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Your test class**:

```
package yourpackage;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PopulateBorrowerTestClass1 {

    //This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
    //is named "test1"
    @DataProvider(name = "test1")
    public Object[][] createData1() {
     return new Object[][] {
       { "PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1Value", "PrimaryBorrowerBaseNameValue" }
     };
    }

    //This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
    //named "test1"
    @Test(dataProvider = "test1")
    public static void PopulateBorrower(String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1, String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName)
    {       
        System.out.println(PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1 + " " + PrimaryBorrowerBaseName);
       //your all code goes here
     }
}
```

Comment: I had this exception  : 
SKIPPED: run
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'primary-borrower-base-name1' is required by (at)Test on method run but has not been marked (at)Optional or defined

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use static function as a test? It should not be static!

Comment: I removed the static--> no luck @Parameters({"PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1","PrimaryBorrowerBaseName  "})
@Test
public void PopulateBorrower(String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName1,String PrimaryBorrowerBaseName)

Comment: You should specify data provider - the function that returns some parameters that the test uses.

Comment: You can read more here http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/

Answer (score 1):

Does your unit test use the @DataProvider annotation (@Parameterized in JUnit 4.11)?  If so, and you have defined a data provider method, then your @Test annotation needs to recognize it as such like so:

```
@Test
@Parameters(value="number", value2="digit")
public void parameterIntTest(int number, int digit) {
    System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + number + " and " + digit);
}
```