# Unable to use variable defined in @BeforeGroup in @Test method

Tags: java, testng

```
I have 3 `@Test` methods in three different classes that extends one base class.
```

Test 1:

```
@Test(groups = "group1")
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("Test1 value : " + var); 
}
```

Test 2:

```
@Test(groups = "group2",dependsOnGroups={"group1"})
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("Test2 value : " + var); 
}
```

Test 3:

```
@Test
public void test3() {
    System.out.println("Test3 value : " + var); 
}
```

Base class:

public class TestBase {

```
public int var = 0;

@BeforeGroups(value = { "group1", "group2" })

void initialize() {

    System.out.println("Before group");

    var = 1; 

}
```

}

I would need the `initialize()` method to get executed before 'test1()' and 'test2()' alone. The value of variable `var` is used only in these methods.

Expected output:

Test : Before group

Test1 value : 1

Test3 value : 0

Test : Before group

Test2 value : 1

But with the above code, value of var in test2 is also 0.
How to fix the code to initialize the variable for methods that belong to groups group1 and group2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
package practise;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class TestBase {
    public int var = 0;

    @BeforeGroups(value = { "group1", "group2" })
    void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Running Before group");
        var = 1;
    }
}

/**
 * @author mrunal
 *
 */
public class SO39910848 extends TestBase {

    @Test(groups = "group1")
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Running test1 with value of var as: " + var);
    }

    @Test(groups = "group2",dependsOnGroups={"group1"})
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Running test2 with value of var as: " + var);
    }

    public void test3() {

    }
}
```

Output:

> Running Before group 
>  Running test1 with value of var as: 1 
>  Running
>   Before group 
>  Running test2 with value of var as: 1 
>  PASSED: test1
>   
>  PASSED: test2
>
> ===============================================
>      
>  Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> ## =============================================== 
>  Default suite 
>  Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Comment: Having the groups in different classes does not work.Code:
public class TestBase {
    public int var = 0;
    @BeforeGroups(value = { "group1", "group2" })
    void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Before group");
        var = 1;
} }
public class TestClass1 extends TestBase {
    @Test(groups = "group1")
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test1 value : " + var);
}}
public class TestClass2 extends TestBase {
    @Test(groups = "group2",dependsOnGroups={"group1"})
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2 value : " + var);
}}

Comment: Output of running the above script is as follows:
     Before group
     Test1 value : 1
     Before group
     Test2 value : 0
Value of var which is set in @BeforeGroups is not reflected in TestClass2 method.

Comment: I thought you don't want to reflect the change set int BeforeGroup of TestClass1.. Can you paste what expected output do you need. If you need to share value of var with everyone then just create a static variable and it will be shared across

Comment: Expected output:
Before group
     
Test1 value : 1
     
Before group
     
Test2 value : 1
     
Test3 value : 0
     
I dont want the value to be shared in all the test methods. I just want the values in test that belongs to the groups.
Also making the variable var as static throws the following error.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected non-static field com.amazon.gam.ingestion.uk.Testing.TestClass1.var

Comment: Few tips: always add code and expected output to OP instead of in the comments. next the non-static field is not coming from TestNG that is something internal to your project. if i understand your output, you want to run initialize method just before any group starts? from the expected output it seems the above code does the same, not sure why would u want Test3 value: 0. is it the case that for the test which do not belong to any group for them var should be 0?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. test1 belongs to group1, test2 belongs to group2. test3 does not belong to any group. I want the initialize method to run before methods of groups group1 and group2 only. So, test1 and test2 should have the value of variable var as 1 while for test3, it should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

First, TestNG creates one instance by child classes where `var` is 0.

Then, it calls `@BeforeGroups` only once on one instance it created before.

If TestNG is working as expected, you should find `var=1` somewhere. 
If you want share the value across all instance, you can use a `static` var or,  better, use the test context: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection and http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestContext.html

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

1. Make `var` as `public` global variable in your base class.
2. Assign value to `var` in you `@BeforeGroups` method.
3. Access `var` in sub classes.

But few things on your test suite set up,

1. Why do you need base and sub class setup?
2. What if you want to initialize `var` with different values while running tests.

If the answer to both questions is, to get `var` value in few tests then you can think of using `TestNG`'s capability of passing parameters to methods annotated with one of `TestNG` annotations.

In such way your code will look more cleaner and composed. You can have a look at [How to supply parameters in TestNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39538359/5155299)

Comment: 1. My base class is the test base with all the common stuff required for the test cases, every sub-class has one/more tests
2. I want the value of var to be same for the tests in the groups group1 and group2.
Actually, the value I would need to use in test is not integer. DB is loaded in BeforeSuite and DB object is created in BeforeGroups which is the one that I am trying to access from test cases.